# Compilation fails using Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: compilation, kotlin, junit4

I am going through the examples in Kotlin in Action book. The gradle buid script is as follows:

```
group 'kotlin-in-action'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src'
}
```

All the scripts compile except for two classes that uses junit.

```
package ch06.ex1_8_1_LateinitializedProperties

import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert

class MyService {
    fun performAction(): String = "foo"
}

class MyTest {
    private var myService: MyService? = null

    @Before fun setUp() {
        myService = MyService()
    }

    @Test fun testAction() {
        Assert.assertEquals("foo",
            myService!!.performAction())
    }
}
```

The compiler says it can't find junit. I have tried adding the jar files in IntelliJ, but this has not resolved the problem. The jar files I have added are junit and hamscrest-core. This is all version 4.12.

Comment: Show your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this. I had to add the Junit and hamcrest-core jar files from the mavan depository.